# Show that $x\subseteq y \Leftrightarrow \mathcal{P}(x)\subseteq\mathcal{P}(y)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Note that $\mathcal{P}(x)$,$\mathcal{P}(y)$ are power sets.

*My proof*.$\left( \Rightarrow \right)$ Let $t\in x$. Then, $t\in y$. So, since $t\in x$, $t\in \mathcal{P}(x)$. Also, since $t\in \mathcal{P}(x)$, $t\in\mathcal{P}(y)$. Thus, $x\subseteq y \Rightarrow  \mathcal{P}(x)\subseteq\mathcal{P}(y)$.

$(\Leftarrow )$. Similar.

**Can you check my proof?**

Comment: "So, since $t\in x$, $t\in\mathcal P(x)$". False: elements of the power set are *subsets* of $x$. One of the axioms of ZFC yields as a corollary that every non-empty set $x$ has an element $t\in x$ such that $t\notin \mathcal P(x)$.

Comment: NO, from $t \in x$ it does not follow that $t \in P(x)$. $P(x)$ is the set of *subsets* of $x$ and an element of $x$ is not necessarily a subset.

Comment: You have to start from: let $t$ and element of $P(x)$, i.e. a subset of $x$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Can you check my answer?

Comment: Everything would be fine if you replaced some $\in$ with $\subseteq$, i.e.: *Let $t \subseteq x$. Then $t \subseteq y$. etc.*.

Answer (score 2):

The proof attempt you provided is incorrect as it stands. For illustration, this is how you could work out one direction (I hope this helps you approach the other direction correctly)

$(\Rightarrow)$ Assume that $x\subseteq y$. Let $z\in \mathcal{P}(x)$. Then $z\subseteq x$. As $z\subseteq x$ and $x\subseteq y$, we get $z\subseteq y$. So $z\in \mathcal{P}(y)$.

Answer (score 1):

I actualy fail to follow your line (although it is wrong to say that $t\in X\Rightarrow t\in \mathcal{P}(X)$, rather that $\{t\}\in\mathcal{P}(X)$)

My attempt:

($\Rightarrow$): let $S\subseteq X\subseteq Y$: the relationship $\subseteq$ is transitive, therefore $S\subseteq Y$ and this implies $\mathcal{P}(X)\subseteq\mathcal{P}(Y)$.

($\Leftarrow$): let $t\in X$: then $\{t\}\in\mathcal{P}(X)\subseteq\mathcal{P}(Y)$, this implies $\{t\}\in\mathcal{P}(Y)$, hence $t\in Y$.

Comment: For $(\Leftarrow)$ there is a simpler way : $x\in \mathcal{P}(x)\subset\mathcal{P}(y)$, and thus $x\subset y$.

Answer (score 1):

*Proof.* $(\Rightarrow)$ Let $t\subseteq x\subseteq y$. Thus, $t\in\mathbb{P}(x)\subseteq\mathbb{P}(y)$.

$(\Leftarrow)$. Let $t\in x$. So, $\{t\}\in\mathbb{P}(x)$. Thus, $\{t\}\in\mathbb{P}(y)$. Thus, $t\in y$. Therefore, $x\subseteq y$.

**Can you check my proof?**

Comment: No again; you are mixing $\in$ with $\subseteq$: they are different *relations* between sets. Let $t \in P(x)$; this means that $t$ is a *subset* of $x$, i.e. $t \subseteq x$. But $\subseteq$ is transitive, and thus $t \subseteq y$, that means $t \in P(y)$. This is true for $t$ whatever, and thus: $P(x) \subseteq P(y)$.

Comment: The second part is fine.

Answer (score 0):

To prove the forward direction $(\Rightarrow)$, you should start by assuming that $x \subseteq y$, then choose an element of $\mathcal{P}(x)$ and show it is in $\mathcal{P}(y)$. Be careful, though - elements of $\mathcal{P}(x)$ are *subsets* of $x$, not elements of $x$. (You seem to be conflating the two as you said "since $t \in x$, $t \in \mathcal{P}(x)$.")

The reverse direction is not "similar" enough to omit the proof, in my opinion. To prove this direction, assume that $\mathcal{P}(x) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(y)$. Now given an element of $x$, why can you conclude that it is in $y$? Can you relate an element of $x$ to an element of $\mathcal{P}(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

No, that doesn't work.

When you want to prove $\mathcal P(x)\subseteq\mathcal P(y)$ it is not enough to find *someting* that is both in $\mathcal P(x)$ and $\mathcal P(y)$ -- you need to show that *everything* in $\mathcal P(x)$ is also in $\mathcal P(y)$.

Furthermore, your reasoning that just becayse $t\in x$ you also have $t\in\mathcal P(x)$ does not hold at all, which separately dooms your argument. Consider for example $x=\{42\}$, and $t=42$. Then $\mathcal P(x)=\{\varnothing, \{42\}\}$, and none of the two elements of $\mathcal P(x)$ equals $t$.

Comment: Can you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal{P}(x) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(y)$

By definition of $\subseteq$, we know $\forall z\in \mathcal{P}(x) \implies z \in \mathcal{P}(y)$

$x \in \mathcal{P}(x)$ since it holds that $x\subseteq x$

So then $x \in \mathcal{P}(y):= \{a: a\subseteq y\}$$\implies  x\subseteq y$

---

Now let $ x\subseteq y$

$b\in \mathcal{P}(x)$ iff $b\subseteq x$ $(\text{definition of the power set})$

$\forall b\in \mathcal{P}(x)\implies  b\subseteq x \subseteq y\implies b\subseteq y\implies b\in  \mathcal{P}(y)$

So $\mathcal{P}(x) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(y)$